# how to find and convert missing values in a pandas dataframe in a HUGE dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

I'm working on a huge data set with size (891221 X 85). each column in the data has different indications of missing or unknown values. so for example: column 1 missing values are indicated with -1 or X, column 2 missing values are indicated with XX and 0 etc.

now i'm trying to loop over each element in the data set and converting each missing value to np.nan using the following code:

```
for i in range(data.shape[1]):
    for j in range(data.shape[0]):
        if data.iloc[j,i] in indicators[i]:
            data.iloc[j,i] = np.nan
```

since the data has about 75 million data entries, this process could take a couple of days. is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
for i,col in enumerate(data.columns):
    for ind in indicators[i]:
        data[col].replace(ind, np.nan)
```

Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html

Comment: Thanks a Ton! i was able to do it in 10 seconds using this. i'm shocked at the difference in performance...